# Why is By.CLASS_NAME in Selenium (Python) use By.CSS_SELECTOR?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I use Selenium I can't use XPATH for this object because it's dynamic or something it can sometimes find it and sometimes not. I would use `By.CLASS_NAME` but when I do it says that the object could not be found and used the method `css_selector`. When I do use the CSS selector, it can't find it too.

Yes, I used the web browser on the exact site to verify they are correct.
Yes, I tried every possible method, including XPATH.
Yes, I did research and could not find anything.

Here's the CSS selector:

```
#app-mount > div.appAsidePanelWrapper-ev4hlp > div.notAppAsidePanel-3yzkgB > div.app-3xd6d0 > div > div > div > form > div.centeringWrapper-dGnJPQ > div > div:nth-child(7) > button
```

Here's the class name:

```
button-1cRKG6 button-ejjZWC lookFilled-1H2Jvj colorBrand-2M3O3N sizeLarge-2xP3-w fullWidth-3M-YBR grow-2T4nbg
```

Here's the code with css selector:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app-mount > div.appAsidePanelWrapper-ev4hlp > div.notAppAsidePanel-3yzkgB > div.app-3xd6d0 > div > div > div > form > div.centeringWrapper-dGnJPQ > div > div:nth-child(7) > button").click()
```

Returning:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#app-mount > div.appAsidePanelWrapper-ev4hlp > div.notAppAsidePanel-3yzkgB > div.app-3xd6d0 > div > div > div > form > div.centeringWrapper-dGnJPQ > div > div:nth-child(7) > button"}
```

Here it is with the class name:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button-1cRKG6 button-ejjZWC lookFilled-1H2Jvj colorBrand-2M3O3N sizeLarge-2xP3-w fullWidth-3M-YBR grow-2T4nbg").click()
```

Returning:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button-1cRKG6 button-ejjZWC lookFilled-1H2Jvj colorBrand-2M3O3N sizeLarge-2xP3-w fullWidth-3M-YBR grow-2T4nbg"}
```

(Notice how it says `{"method":"css selector"`)

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: It looks like `BY.CLASS_NAME` requires a **single** class name, and it gets translated into a CSS selector (`.<class_name>`).